# Uploading Multiple Files to Google Drive with Google App Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload multiple files at once with my app. It recognizes when there are 2 or more files being selected. However, it will only upload the 1st file that is selected to my drive. Also (although quite minor), I was wondering how I can change my textarea font to be Times New Roman to stay consistent with the rest of the font.

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {
    var foldertitle = form.zone + ' | Building: ' + form.building + ' | ' + form.propertyAddress + ' | ' + form.attachType;
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B7UEz7SKB72HfmNmNnlSM2NDTVVUSlloa1hZeVI0VEJuZUhSTmc4UXYwZjV1eWM5YXJPaGs");
    var createfolder = folders.createFolder(foldertitle);
    folder = createfolder;
    var blob = form.filename;
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);
    file.setDescription(" " + form.fileText);

    return "File(s) uploaded successfully! Here is the link to your file(s):     " + folder.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('err: ' + error.toString());
    return error.toString();
  }

}

function uploadArquivoParaDrive(base64Data, nomeArq, idPasta) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(nomeArq);

    var file = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B7UEz7SKB72HfmNmNnlSM2NDTVVUSlloa1hZeVI0VEJuZUhSTmc4UXYwZjV1eWM5YXJPaGs").createFile(ss);

    return file.getName();
  }catch(e){
    return 'Erro: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
```

form.html

```
<body>
  <div id="formcontainer">

    <label for="myForm">Facilities Project Database Attachment Uploader:</label>

    <br><br>


    <form id="myForm"> 
      <label for="myForm">Project Details:</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="zone" placeholder="Zone:">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="building" placeholder="Building(s):">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="propertyAddress" placeholder="Property Address:">
      </div>
      <div>

      <label for="fileText">Project Description:</label>

          <TEXTAREA name="projectDescription" 
          placeholder="Describe your attachment(s) here:"
          style ="width:400px; height:200px;"
          ></TEXTAREA>


      </div> 
      <br>


      <label for="attachType">Choose Attachment Type:</label>
      <br>
      <select name="attachType">
        <option value="Pictures Only">Picture(s)</option>
        <option value="Proposals Only">Proposal(s)</option>
        <option value="Pictures & Proposals">All</option>
      </select>
      <br>

      <label for="myFile">Upload Attachment(s):</label>
      <br>


      <input type="file" name="filename" id="myFile" multiple>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="iteratorFileUpload()">


    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="output"></div>

  <script>
    function iteratorFileUpload() {
        var allFiles = document.getElementById('myFile').files;

    if (allFiles.length == 0) {
        alert('No file selected!');
            } else {

    // Send each file one at a time
    var i=0;
    for (i=0; i < allFiles.total; i+=1) {
      console.log('This iteration: ' + i);
      sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i]);
          };
        };
      };

    function sendFileToDrive(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
        var content = reader.result;
        console.log('Sending ' + file.name);

        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
          .uploadArquivoParaDrive(content, file.name, currFolder);
     }

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     };
  </script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  // Upload de arquivo dentro das pastas Arquivos Auxiliares
    function iterarArquivosUpload() {
    var arquivos = document.getElementById('inputUpload').files;

    if (arquivos.length == 0) {
        alert('No file selected!');
    } else {
        //Show Progress Bar
        numUploads.total = arquivos.length;
        $('.progressUpload').progressbar({
            value : false
        });
        $('.labelProgressUpload').html('Preparando arquivos para upload');

        // Send each file at a time
        for (var arqs = 0; arqs < numUploads.total; arqs++) {
            console.log(arqs);
            enviarArquivoParaDrive(arquivos[arqs]);
        }
    }
}

function enviarArquivoParaDrive(arquivo) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var content = reader.result;
        console.log('Sending ' + arquivo.name);
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadArquivoParaDrive(content, arquivo.name, currFolder);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(arquivo);
}

function updateProgressbar( idUpdate ){
   console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
   numUploads.done++;
   var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total)*100);
   $('.progressUpload').progressbar({value: porc });
   $('.labelProgressUpload').html(numUploads.done +'/'+ numUploads.total);
   if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
      uploadsFinished();
      numUploads.done = 0;
   };
}
</script>

  <script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }

  </script>

  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 400px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    input {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      ‌​ -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    select {
      margin: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      width: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
    }
    input[type="file"] {
      padding: 5px 0px 15px 0px !important;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

Comment: I think that currently the multiple file upload input tag doesn't work with HTML Service in Apps Script.

Comment: Did you get the code above to work at all because it's not working on my end.

Comment: @SandyGood Check my answer, maybe it's out of scope but it's a Multiple File Upload working in GAS.

Comment: Apps Script HTML *WILL* pass **one** file of the multiple files in the multiple file input tag. But it's pointless to use an attribute of `multiple`, if you only get one file.  If you use `form.filename`, you get a `FileUpload` object.  From that FileUpload object, you can get the file name, and the file `contents` and the `name`.  For example:  `form.filename.name` gives you the file name `form.filename.contents` gives you the file contents.  But again, problem is, that there is only one file there.  `google.script.run` *can* make multiple concurrent calls to the server.

Comment: So, you could have multiple, single file input tags.

Comment: @SandyGood So should I just remove multiple? How would I implement form.filename into my code?

Comment: Well, I think that @Kriggs answer is probably the best solution if you want to use the `multiple` attribute.  I'm looking at how it works now.

Comment: @SandyGood How did you get it to work? I'm not sure where to add that into the code.

Comment: See my answer for where to start.  @Kriggs actually answered the question, so I don't want to take anything away, but to much info for the comment section.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I know this question is old, but after finding it and related ones, I was never able to get the multiple file upload working. So after a lot of banging my head against walls, I wanted to post a full example (.html and .gs) in case anyone in the future is looking for one to get started. This is working when I deploy it right now and will hopefully work for other people out there. Note that I just hardcoded the folder in the drive to use in the code.gs file, but that can be easily changed.

form.html:

```
<body>
  <div id="formcontainer">

    <label for="myForm">Facilities Project Database Attachment Uploader:</label>

    <br><br>


    <form id="myForm"> 
      <label for="myForm">Project Details:</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="zone" placeholder="Zone:">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="building" placeholder="Building(s):">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="propertyAddress" placeholder="Property Address:">
      </div>
      <div>

      <label for="fileText">Project Description:</label>

          <TEXTAREA name="projectDescription" 
          placeholder="Describe your attachment(s) here:"
          style ="width:400px; height:200px;"
          ></TEXTAREA>


      </div> 
      <br>


      <label for="attachType">Choose Attachment Type:</label>
      <br>
      <select name="attachType">
        <option value="Pictures Only">Picture(s)</option>
        <option value="Proposals Only">Proposal(s)</option>
        <option value="Pictures & Proposals">All</option>
      </select>
      <br>

      <label for="myFile">Upload Attachment(s):</label>
      <br>


      <input type="file" name="filename" id="myFile" multiple>

      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="iteratorFileUpload()">


    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="output"></div>
<div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress-label"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

var numUploads = {};
numUploads.done = 0;
numUploads.total = 0;

// Upload the files into a folder in drive
// This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
function iteratorFileUpload() {
    var allFiles = document.getElementById('myFile').files;

    if (allFiles.length == 0) {
        alert('No file selected!');
    } else {
        //Show Progress Bar

        numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value : false
        });//.append("<div class='caption'>37%</div>");
        $(".progress-label").html('Preparing files for upload');
        // Send each file at a time
        for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i]);
        }
    }
}

function sendFileToDrive(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var content = reader.result;
        console.log('Sending ' + file.name);
        var currFolder = 'Something';
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, currFolder);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function updateProgressbar( idUpdate ){
   console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
   numUploads.done++;
   var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total)*100);
   $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: porc });
   $(".progress-label").text(numUploads.done +'/'+ numUploads.total);
   if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
      //uploadsFinished();
      numUploads.done = 0;
   };
}
</script>

  <script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }

  </script>

  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 400px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    input {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      ‌​ -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    select {
      margin: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      width: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
    }
    input[type="file"] {
      padding: 5px 0px 15px 0px !important;
    }
#progressbar{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.progress-label {
      float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
          width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(fileName);

    var dropbox = "Something"; // Folder Name
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    var file = folder.createFile(ss);

    return file.getName();
  }catch(e){
    return 'Error: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @barragan thanks for sharing your code! It does exactly what its supposed to.

As of right now, the files are simply being placed into the initial "something" folder. I'm trying to figure out how to make each group of uploaded files be uploaded into its own individual folder within this folder.

Comment: Useful starting point to develop a form that upload multiple files on Google Drive. Many thanks!

Comment: @bobatapioca In the code.gs file, once you get the folder that you want to make the individual folders in, you can use that folder object and the createFolder() function (documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder) ) to make a new folder. And then instead of using createFile() from the base folder, you can do the same with the subfolder you just created. Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that you dont need an actual form in the client HTML of modern browsers. You can use var fd = new FormData(); fd.append("upload1", blob1); ...; xmlHttpRequest.send(fd);

Comment: This is fantastic @barragan thank you! i've spent all night hunting for it through a million wrong answers online, it seems to be an issue many others have struggled with, particularly the 5mb upload limit. i wish this comment had higher visibility, would've saved so much time. 

havent worked out where your fields (building, address, etc) go to yet, though i don't really need those anyway

Comment: as this is the best answer i found on for a question many people were asking i've done a bit of development on the design of it, still a few bugs and chrome seems to run out of memory pretty often.

Comment: as this is the best answer i found on for a question many people are asking, i've done a bit of development on the design which i'd like to share. still a few bugs to iron out and chrome seems to run out of memory pretty often on large files.

the code is too long for this comment so i'll add it at the bottom of this page

Comment: This is amazing!

Comment: You saved my day @barragan

Answer (score 7):

### Updated For May 2017

I updated and improved barragan's answer.

Advantages:

1. Allows users to create a subfolder name to contain all the files uploaded during this session
2. Ensures that these subfolders all exist within one specified folder within your Google Drive
3. The page/form is mobile-responsive

You can start with [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fr9KAJQoWsk) just to create the script and get to know the basics.

Then you can completely replace **form.html** with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>
            Send Files
        </title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>        
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {

                function afterSubfolderCreated(subfolderId) {
                    console.log(subfolderId);
                    console.log(allFiles);
                    numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
                    $('#progressbar').progressbar({
                        value: false
                    });
                    $(".progress-label").html('Preparing files for upload');
                    for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
                        console.log(i);
                        sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i], subfolderId);
                    }
                }

                function sendFileToDrive(file, subfolderId) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var content = reader.result;
                        console.log('Sending ' + file.name);
                        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, subfolderId);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }

                function updateProgressbar(idUpdate) {
                    console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
                    numUploads.done++;
                    var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total) * 100);
                    $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: porc});
                    $(".progress-label").text(numUploads.done + '/' + numUploads.total);
                    if (numUploads.done == numUploads.total) {                        
                        numUploads.done = 0;
                        $(".progress-label").text($(".progress-label").text() + ': FINISHED!');
                        $("#progressbar").after('(Optional) Refresh this page if you remembered other screenshots you want to add.');//<a href="javascript:window.top.location.href=window.top.location.href"> does not work
                    }
                }

                function fileUploaded(status) {
                    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
                }
                var numUploads = {};
                numUploads.done = 0;
                numUploads.total = 0;
                var allFiles;
                var frm = $('#myForm');
                frm.submit(function () {
                    allFiles = document.getElementById('myFile').files;
                    if (!frm.checkValidity || frm.checkValidity()) {
                        if (allFiles.length == 0) {
                            alert('Error: Please choose at least 1 file to upload.');
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            frm.hide();
                            var subfolderName = document.getElementById('myName').value;
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '',//URL of webhook endpoint for sending a Slack notification
                                data: {
                                     title: subfolderName + ' is uploading screenshots',
                                     message: ''
                                }
                            });
                            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSubfolderCreated).createSubfolder(subfolderName);
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('Invalid form');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });//end docReady
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding: 20px;
                margin: auto;
                font-size: 20px;
            }
            label{
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            input{
                font-size: 20px;
                padding: 5px;
                display: inline-block;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                ‌-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .hint{
                font-size: 90%;
                color: #666;
            }
            select {
                margin: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
            }
            input[type="file"] {
                padding: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
            }
            #progressbar{
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: relative;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
            .progress-label {
                float: left;
                margin-top: 5px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
            li{
               padding: 10px;
            }
            @media only screen and (max-width : 520px) {
                #logo {
                    max-width: 100%;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <img src="" id="logo">
        </p>
        <p>This webpage allows you to send me screenshots of your dating profiles.</p>
        <ol>
            <li>
                In each of your dating apps, take a screenshot <a href="https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/" target="_blank">(how?)</a> of every part of every page of your profile.
            </li>
            <li>
                Do the same for each of your photos (at full resolution).
            </li>
            <li>
                In the form below, type your first name and last initial (without any spaces or special characters), such as SallyT.
            </li>
            <li>
                Then click the first button and select all of your screenshot images (all at once).
            </li>
            <li>
                Finally, press the last button to send them all to me!
            </li>
        </ol>
        <form id="myForm"> 
            <div>
                <label for="myName">Your first name and last initial:</label> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" placeholder="SallyT" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" value=""> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="hint">(No spaces or special characters allowed because this will determine your folder name)</span>
                </div>            
            <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <label for="myFile">Screenshot image files:</label>

                <input type="file" name="filename" id="myFile" multiple>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <input type="submit" value="Send File(s) ➔" >
            </div>
        </form>

        <div id="output"></div>
        <div id="progressbar">
            <div class="progress-label"></div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

And completely replace **server.gs** with this:

```
function doGet() {
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form');
  output.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');// See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42681526/470749
  return output.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName, subfolderId) {
  Logger.log(subfolderId);
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(fileName);
    var subfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(subfolderId);
    var file = subfolder.createFile(ss);
    Logger.log(file);
    return file.getName() + ' at ' + file.getUrl();
  } catch(e){
    return 'createFile Error: ' + e.toString();
  }
}

function createSubfolder(subfolderName){
  var dropbox = subfolderName + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "US/Eastern", "_yyyy-MM-dd");
    Logger.log(dropbox);
    var parentFolderId = "{ID such as 0B9iQ20nrMNYAaHZxRjd}";
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
    var folder;
    try {
      folder = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(dropbox).next();      
    }
    catch(e) {
      folder = parentFolder.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    Logger.log(folder);
  return folder.getId();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, how to trigger this from menu ? which func starts first ?

Answer (score 4):

Joining the pile of older answers, but this really helped me when I implemented my own file multi upload for getting files into Google Drive using the DriveApp V3 api.

I wrote and posted my own solution here: https://github.com/CharlesPlucker/drive-multi-upload/

Improvements:
- Handles multiple files sequentially
- Handles large > 50MB files
- Validation

I wrapped my google api calls into promises since I was running into timing issues when creating a folder and immediately trying to fetch it by name reference. Each one of my promises will only resolve when its file is fully uploaded. To get that working I had to use a Promise Factory. I'll be glad to explain this code if the need arises!

Comment: Thank you Charles, this is the perfect example for my needs. I just tested it and it was able to upload a 2Gb file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to send a file at a time trough the script.run, here's my implementation with FileReaders/ReadAsURL, which makes the file a Base64 string, which can be easily passed around:

Notes:

1. Dunno if it's necessary but I'm using IFRAME sandbox
2. I left the progressBar in the code, you can remove it
3. Everything must be OUTSIDE a form
4. It accepts any file type

HTML:

```
// Upload de arquivo dentro das pastas Arquivos Auxiliares
function iterarArquivosUpload() {
    var arquivos = document.getElementById('inputUpload').files;

    if (arquivos.length == 0) {
        alert('No file selected!');
    } else {
        //Show Progress Bar
        numUploads.total = arquivos.length;
        $('.progressUpload').progressbar({
            value : false
        });
        $('.labelProgressUpload').html('Preparando arquivos para upload');

        // Send each file at a time
        for (var arqs = 0; arqs < numUploads.total; arqs++) {
            console.log(arqs);
            enviarArquivoParaDrive(arquivos[arqs]);
        }
    }
}

function enviarArquivoParaDrive(arquivo) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var content = reader.result;
        console.log('Sending ' + arquivo.name);
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadArquivoParaDrive(content, arquivo.name, currFolder);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(arquivo);
}

function updateProgressbar( idUpdate ){
   console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
   numUploads.done++;
   var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total)*100);
   $('.progressUpload').progressbar({value: porc });
   $('.labelProgressUpload').html(numUploads.done +'/'+ numUploads.total);
   if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
      uploadsFinished();
      numUploads.done = 0;
   };
}
```

Code.GS

```
function uploadArquivoParaDrive(base64Data, nomeArq, idPasta) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(nomeArq);

    var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(idPasta).createFile(ss);

    return file.getName();
  }catch(e){
    return 'Erro: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as @barragan's answer here is the best answer i found after hours and hours of searching for a question many people were asking, i've done a bit of development to improve the design a bit for others as a thanks. still a few bugs and chrome seems to run out of memory and give up with any file over 100MB

[here's a live version](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzAq_z7zVveuFV3doC4jLhKHRmNYkCHjAwiUxqJH6kA2o1QvYk/exec)

**server.gs**

```
'function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(fileName);

    var dropbox = "Something"; // Folder Name
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    var file = folder.createFile(ss);

    return file.getName();
  }catch(e){
    return 'Error: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
'
```

**form.html**

```
<head>
    <base target="_blank">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Focallocal Uploader</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
  <div align="center">
    <p><img src="http://news.focallocal.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/FOCALLOCAL-Website-Text-Header.png" width="80%"></p> 
  </div> 
</head>

<body>


  <div id="formcontainer" width="50%">

    <label for="myForm">Focallocal Community G.Drive Uploader</label>

  <br>

  <br>
    <form id="myForm" width="50%"> 
      <label for="myForm">Details</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="your name">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="gathering" placeholder="which fabulous Positive Action you're sending us">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="the town/village/city and country month brightend by positivity">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="date of the beautiful action">
      </div>
      <div  width="100%" height="200px">

      <label for="fileText">would you like to leave a short quote?</label>

          <TEXTAREA name="Quote" 
          placeholder="many people would love to share in your experience. if you have more than a sentence or two to write, why not writing an article the Community News section of our website?"         
          ></TEXTAREA>


      </div> 
      <br>


      <br>

      <label for="myFile">Upload Your Files:</label>
      <br>


      <input type="file" name="filename" id="myFile" multiple>

      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="iteratorFileUpload();">



    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="output"></div>
<div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress-label"></div>   


</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>

var numUploads = {};
numUploads.done = 0;
numUploads.total = 0;

// Upload the files into a folder in drive
// This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
function iteratorFileUpload() {
    var allFiles = document.getElementById('myFile').files;

    if (allFiles.length == 0) {
        alert('No file selected!');
    } else {
        //Show Progress Bar

        numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value : false
        });//.append("<div class='caption'>37%</div>");
        $(".progress-label").html('Preparing files for upload');
        // Send each file at a time
        for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i]);
        }
    }
}

function sendFileToDrive(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var content = reader.result;
        console.log('Sending ' + file.name);
        var currFolder = 'Something';
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, currFolder);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function updateProgressbar( idUpdate ){
   console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
   numUploads.done++;
   var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total)*100);
   $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: porc });
   $(".progress-label").text(numUploads.done +'/'+ numUploads.total);
   if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
      //uploadsFinished();
      numUploads.done = 0;
   };
}
</script>

  <script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }

  </script>

  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 60%;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    input {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      ‌​ -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    select {
      margin: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      width: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
    }
    input[type="file"] {
      padding: 5px 0px 15px 0px !important;
    }
#progressbar{
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.progress-label {
      float: left;
      margin-top: 5px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
      width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

i wasn't able to get the text fields to send an email with the details out, and ran out of time before working out how to hook them up to a Google Spreadsheet, so for the moment they don't record the information added

as an added bonus, it looked fabulous with is in the form.html

```
      <div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
      <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
        <i class="large material-icons">menu</i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="btn-floating red"  href="https://focallocal-a-positive-action-movement.myshopify.com/" target="_blank" title="Pimp your Cool at the Positive Action Shop"><i class="material-icons">monetization_on</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating blue"  href="https://www.youtube.com/user/Focallocal" target="_blank" title="Follow the Positive Action Youtube Channel"><i class="material-icons">video_library</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating green" href="http://focallocal.org/" target="_blank" title="Read our About Us Page"><i class="material-icons">help</i></a></li>
      </ul>

   </div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad.js"></script>
```

i took it out again as some of the scripts being called in were causing issues. if anyone can fix them it they add a lot to the appearance and functionality of the form

*edit: i've been playing around with it and only around half of the files sent seem to arrive, so there are still some issues with both of the codes here atm