# Modify an HTML object with Javascript in a Google Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Like much of other examples provided by Google on Google scripts, modifying HTML through Javascript inside a success handler doesn't seem to work.

The example is:

```
<script>
  function updateUrl(url) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Got it!</a>';
  }
</script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="myFile" type="file" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

And I've done something quite similar:

```
<script>
    function clearList(someValue){
        document.getElementById('studentsForm').reset()
    }
    function setStatus(someValue){
        var status = document.getElementById('status');
        status.innerHTML = 'Remark posted.'
    }
</script>

<form name='studentsForm' id='studentsForm'>
    <select name='student'>
        <option value='none'>Select a student...</option>
        options
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea name='comment' rows='10' cols='35'>Type your comment here</textarea><br><br>
    <input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='google.script.run
                                                 .withSuccessHandler(setStatus)
                                                 .processRemark(this.parentNode)'>
</form>
<div id="status"></div>
```

I've tried running both clearList() and setStatus() functions but neither affected the HTML GUI even thought the server-side function was run successfully.

Is there something else to be done for this to work? Thanks.

**Edit:**
In fact, to illustrate the problem isn't about a server-client communication issue (as far as I understand it), here is a simplified version of the code, with which the HTML isn't modified through the script function call:

```
<script>
function setStatus(){
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.innerHTML = 'Remark posted.'
}
</script>
<input type='button' value='Test' onclick='setStatus();'>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just realised the input file, it doesn't work that way with IFRAME sandbox, see [issue 4610](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4610), a workaround is present in the posts.

Here's my workaround for multiple files:
[Uploading Multiple Files to Google Drive with Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126181/uploading-multiple-files-to-google-drive-with-google-app-script/31139392#31139392)

Comment: What is the input file you are referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I'll need a bit more of guidance please. I'm not sure to understand what the problem is in the first place.

Comment: Your first HTML code has an `<input type="file"` field, these ones doesn't work with the IFRAME sandbox, the you need to set in the `doGet` function on the `code.gs` file. For it to return something you need to remove it from the form and do as Sandy Good says in the post below mine. Also need to review the function `processForm` and `processRemark`, they may be the culprit also.

Comment: The bug comments specify: "Forms without file inputs should work correctly." However, in my case I'm not trying to upload a file. I'm simply submitting the form and expect a return to the HTML so I can amend the HTML. That return doesn't work though.

Comment: I've updated the op with a simplified HTML showing how the HTML doesn't get modified through a script call, even though I'm not making any call to a server-side function.