# How to create image file on google drive having BinaryString or any of FileReader options

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, filereader

I'm passing data to the google application wich published on the web using Post method. Here is the code of the sever side:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var params, result, responce;
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined')
    params = (e.parameters);
    if (params['type'] == 'get') {
     //do the get;
    }
    else {
    try {
      result = reformat_src(e.parameters);
      responce = process_result(result);
    }
    catch(e) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(responce));

}

function reformat_src(request) {
  var prop, obj;
  obj = {};
  for (prop in request) {
    obj[prop] = request[prop][0];
  }
  return obj;
}
```

In process_result function I'm trying to create an image file on google drive

```
function process_result(result) {
  var folder;
  folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  folder.createFile('test', result['blob'], MimeType.PNG);
}
```

I know that result['blob'] contains the png file that I've got with

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
```

But I failed to create a file. Does anybody know how to create an image file having data from FileReader? I can pass to GAS any of type: 

readAsBinaryString

readAsText

readAsDataURL

readAsArrayBuffer
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As usual I found answer by myself. I need to use readAsDataURL and this function:

```
function uploadArquivoParaDrive(base64Data, nomeArq, idPasta) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(nomeArq);

    var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(idPasta).createFile(ss);

    return file.getName();
  }catch(e){
    return 'Erro: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
```

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126181/uploading-multiple-files-to-google-drive-with-google-app-script/31139392#31139392)