# How to Add a file to Google Drive via Docs Add On using App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

Here is my scenario.  I've created an Add-On for Google Docs that acts as a video toolbox.

A feature I'm trying to add is the ability to record a video using the built in web cam (using videojs-recorder) and then link to that video within the doc. I've got the video part working, but not sure how to get the webm JS Blob converted into a Google Blob so I can create a file on the users Google Drive for sharing and linking.

Just to figure out how this might work this is what I've done so far without any luck.

**CLIENT SIDE CODE**

```
//event handler for video recording finish   
vidrecorder.on('finishRecord', function()
{
    // the blob object contains the recorded data that
    // can be downloaded by the user, stored on server etc.
    console.log('finished recording: ', vidrecorder.recordedData);
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){
        console.log("winning");
    }).saveBlob(vidrecorder.recordedData);
});
```

**SERVER SIDE CODE**

```
function saveBlob(blob) {
    Logger.log("Uploaded %s of type %s and size %s.",
            blob.name,
            blob.size, 
            blob.type);
}
```

The errors I get seem to be related to serialization of the blob. But really the exceptions aren't very useful - and just point to some minimized code.

EDIT: Note that there is no FORM object involved here, hence no form POST, and no FileUpload objects, as others have indicated that [this might be a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126181), however it's slightly different in that we are getting a Blob object and need to save it to the server.

Comment: use the answer above to send a form. then send the form in apps script with https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks goes to Zig Mandel and Steve Webster who provided some insight from the [G+ discussion](https://plus.google.com/115669824882832100627/posts/hMF5P99f664) regarding this.

I finally pieced together enough bits to get this working.

CLIENT CODE

```
        vidrecorder.on('finishRecord', function()
        {
            // the blob object contains the recorded data that
            // can be downloaded by the user, stored on server etc.
            console.log('finished recording: ', vidrecorder.recordedData.video);
            var blob = vidrecorder.recordedData.video;

            var reader = new window.FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                b64Blob = reader.result;
                 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(state){
                        console.log("winning: ", state);
                 }).saveB64Blob(b64Blob);
            };

        });
```

SERVER CODE

```
function saveB64Blob(b64Blob) {
    var success = { success: false, url: null};
    Logger.log("Got blob: %s", b64Blob);
    try {
        var blob = dataURItoBlob(b64Blob);
        Logger.log("GBlob: %s", blob);
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
        file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.COMMENT);
        success = { success: true, url: file.getUrl() };
    } catch (error) {
        Logger.log("Error: %s", error);
    }
    return success;
}

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = Utilities.base64Decode(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = decodeURI(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    return Utilities.newBlob(byteString, mimeString, "video.webm");
}
```

Comment: The link provided to G+ discussion is no more available