# Uploading Multiple Files to Google Drive with Google App Script to specific (from input) folder

Tags: file, google-apps-script, drive

i have problem with this code(which was created by another user)
https://script.google.com/d/1mML9s61tm1WB_xu73tWV0ngTJA2BFr9Q-IGKSZFBaZQYcUInZjfzeoQ1/edit?usp=sharing

How can i change var dropbox = **"Something"**; (folder name in server.gs)

to (folder name typed by user who's sending that email) `<input type="text" name="myFolder" placeholder="type folder name">` from form.html?

I don't know how to edit this because nothing is working.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126181/uploading-multiple-files-to-google-drive-with-google-app-script

Answer (score 1):

In short:

- remove the 'var dropbox = "mielony";' line 14 from code.gs
- pass the form.myFolder value through your function chain so that it is provided to uploadFileToDrive() as the third argument.