# Google Script Video Upload Fails

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps

I am very new to Google Scripts - like I just started learning how to use it yesterday. I have put together a google drive dropzone based on code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777747/3052484). I have my script working, and it uploads photos to the correct folder. The problem is, I am not able to upload files larger than 10mb, and I need to be able to upload video. I did a little research, and I found other questions addressing the same issue, but none of them had a solution to the problem.

*Sorry for the messy code since this is another projet I modified.*

Here is `form.html`:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/min/dropzone.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:900" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex-center-wrap">
    <div class="flex-center">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2>Media Dropzone</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form class="dropzone" id="myForm" action="#">
            <div class="fallback">
              <input name="file" type="file" multiple/>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div id="status" class="hidden">
            <br>
            <p id="status-message"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var numUploads = {};
      numUploads.done = 0;
      numUploads.total = 0;

      var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myForm", { url: "#"});
      myDropzone.on("addedfile", function() {
        iteratorFileUpload();
      });

      // Upload the files into a folder in drive
      // This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
      function iteratorFileUpload() {
        myDropzone.disable();
        var allFiles = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].files;
        if (allFiles.length == 0) {
          alert('No file selected!');
        } else {
          numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
          $("#status").removeClass("hidden");
          $("#status-message").text("Uploading file " + numUploads.done + " of " + numUploads.total + "...");
          for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
            sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i]);
          }
        }
      }

      function sendFileToDrive(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          var content = reader.result;
          console.log('Sending ' + file.name);
          var currFolder = 'Something';
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){
            numUploads.done = numUploads.done + 1;
            if(numUploads.done !== numUploads.total){
              $("#status-message").text("Uploading file " + numUploads.done + " of " + numUploads.total + "...");
            } else{
              $("#status-message").text("Uploading finished!");
            }
            
          }).withFailureHandler(function(e){
            alert(e.message);
          }).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, currFolder);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    });
  </script>

  <style>
    body, html{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    html{
      height: 100%;
    }

    body{
      min-height: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      background-color: #3498db;
    }

    .flex-center-wrap{
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-flex;
      display: -o-flex;
      display: -ms-flex;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .flex-center{
      position: relative;
      max-height: 80vh;
      width: 500px;
      max-width: 90vw;
    }
    
    .dropzone{
      height: 300px;
      border: 3px dashed  #3498db;
    }
    
    .dropzone .dz-message{
      margin: 117px 0 !important;
    }

    .dz-progress,
    .dz-error-message,
    .dz-success-mark,
    .dz-error-mark{
      display: none !important;
    }
    
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
      margin: 10px 0;
    }
    
    p{
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

And here is `server.gs`:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(fileName);

    var folder;

    try{
      folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(""); //removed this for security
    } catch(e){
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder("social-media-dropzone");
    }

    var file = folder.createFile(ss);
    return file.getName();
  } catch(e){
    return 'Error: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
```

Is there any way to increase the limit, or should I scrap this method and try something other than Google scripts?

And here is `server.gs` using the Advanced Drive API:

```
function doGet() {
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  output.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
  return output;
}

function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName) {
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(fileName);

    //var file = folder.createFile(ss);
    var folderId = ""; //removed for security
    var file = {
      title: fileName,
      mimeType: ss.type,
      parents: [{id: folderId }]
    };
    Drive.Files.insert(file, ss);

    return null;
}
```

Even with the advanced API, uploads fail when they get too big. I tested it with an 8mb video and a 15mb video, and the latter failed.

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script wouldn't be my first choice. It depends a little on your use case, but I would probably go with a pure client-side JavaScript approach.

Whatever client you go with, you will need to use resumable upload. I believe this is available to Apps Script via the Advanced Drive Service. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive and https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update

Comment: I got the advanced service working, but it still fails when I try and upload a 15mb video. If I upload a 8mb video it works. Do I have to do any additional setup to increase the limit? I am still running this on App Script. I will add the new backend code to the question.

Comment: I guess I did not implement the resumable upload yet. Do you think that is what is breaking it?

Comment: I check Logger and this is the error I am getting `[17-03-30 11:12:17:216 PDT] Exception: Empty response`.

Comment: there are no limits that you can request an increase for.

Comment: Based on the new code I posted how would I implement resumable uploads? I am having trouble finding documentation - at least examples I understand.