# Multiple file upload form that sends files directly to Google Drive

Tags: forms, file, asynchronous, web, upload

I'm currently trying to develop a web form that uses HTML so that users can visit this webpage and drag and drop thousands of photos. After providing an email address, these photos would be directly sent to one of our Google Drive accounts inside a subfolder of the user's email address and the time of submission.

I've played around with this code, but nowhere did I find a place for me to connect my Google Drive account.

```html
<body>
  <div id="formcontainer">

    <label for="myForm">Facilities Project Database Attachment Uploader:</label>

    <br><br>


    <form id="myForm"> 
      <label for="myForm">Project Details:</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="zone" placeholder="Zone:">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="building" placeholder="Building(s):">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="propertyAddress" placeholder="Property Address:">
      </div>
      <div>

      <label for="fileText">Project Description:</label>

          <TEXTAREA name="projectDescription" 
          placeholder="Describe your attachment(s) here:"
          style ="width:400px; height:200px;"
          ></TEXTAREA>


      </div> 
      <br>


      <label for="attachType">Choose Attachment Type:</label>
      <br>
      <select name="attachType">
        <option value="Pictures Only">Picture(s)</option>
        <option value="Proposals Only">Proposal(s)</option>
        <option value="Pictures & Proposals">All</option>
      </select>
      <br>

      <label for="myFile">Upload Attachment(s):</label>
      <br>


      <input type="file" name="filename" id="myFile" multiple>

      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="iteratorFileUpload()">


    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="output"></div>
<div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress-label"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

var numUploads = {};
numUploads.done = 0;
numUploads.total = 0;

// Upload the files into a folder in drive
// This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
function iteratorFileUpload() {
    var allFiles = document.getElementById('myFile').files;

    if (allFiles.length == 0) {
        alert('No file selected!');
    } else {
        //Show Progress Bar

        numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value : false
        });//.append("<div class='caption'>37%</div>");
        $(".progress-label").html('Preparing files for upload');
        // Send each file at a time
        for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i]);
        }
    }
}

function sendFileToDrive(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var content = reader.result;
        console.log('Sending ' + file.name);
        var currFolder = 'Something';
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, currFolder);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function updateProgressbar( idUpdate ){
   console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
   numUploads.done++;
   var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total)*100);
   $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: porc });
   $(".progress-label").text(numUploads.done +'/'+ numUploads.total);
   if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
      //uploadsFinished();
      numUploads.done = 0;
   };
}
</script>

  <script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }

  </script>

  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 400px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    input {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      ‌​ -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    select {
      margin: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      width: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
    }
    input[type="file"] {
      padding: 5px 0px 15px 0px !important;
    }
#progressbar{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.progress-label {
      float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
          width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

Source: [Uploading Multiple Files to Google Drive with Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126181/uploading-multiple-files-to-google-drive-with-google-app-script)