# I don't understand why it occurred Uncaught TypeError: Failed due to illegal value in property: 0

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

It is Google Apps Script for uploading files to Drive with the ability to continuously add input, and it is encountering

Google Apps Script

```
function uploadFileToDrive(form) {
  try {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1awa5VnzLNVfcFs6LVgJSO-3x8M9NSRI0'); // แทนรหัสโฟลเดอร์ของคุณที่นี่
    var filesUploaded = 0;

    // วนลูปเพื่ออัปโหลดไฟล์ที่เลือกจากทุก input
    for (var i = 0; i < form.myFile.length; i++) {
      var blob = form.myFile[i];
      var file = folder.createFile(blob);
      filesUploaded++;
    }
    
    return 'อัปโหลดไฟล์ ' + filesUploaded + ' ไฟล์เรียบร้อยแล้ว';
  } catch (e) {
    return 'เกิดข้อผิดพลาดในการอัปโหลดไฟล์: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
```

html

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div id="inputContainer">
      <input type="file" name="myFile">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="เพิ่ม input" onclick="addInput()">
    <input type="button" value="อัปโหลด" onclick="uploadFile()">
  </form>
  <div id="output"></div>
```

javascript

```
<script>
    function addInput() {
      var inputContainer = document.getElementById('inputContainer');
      var newInput = document.createElement('input');
      newInput.type = 'file';
      newInput.name = 'myFile';
      inputContainer.appendChild(newInput);
    }

    function uploadFile() {
      var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
      var formData = new FormData(form);

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateOutput).uploadFileToDrive(formData);
    }

    function updateOutput(response) {
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = response;
    }
  </script>
```

I would like to have an example of how to fix this.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126181/uploading-multiple-files-to-google-drive-with-google-app-script